# Edit mode doesn't show boolean difference

Tags: modifiers, edit-mode

After performing a boolean difference via python my object looks like this:
[image]

Now I want to delete the lower part of the object. I wanted to do this in Edit mode: separate by loose parts, but the object looks like this in edit mode and the separate does not work:

[image]

Does anyone know how I can change the mesh in edit mode so I see the different parts and I can apply the separate by loose parts? Or does anyone know another easy way to separate loose parts?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  The Boolean Modifier has an option button that looks like a plane's vertices and edges. The button enables Edit Mode display of the modifier.  Enable it.

[image: Enabled edit mode modifier]

[image: Cube showing result]

Oops, I only answered the question about visibility.  To be able to separate the parts, you have to *apply* the Boolean operator

- select the object the operator is applied to.
- In *Object Mode* go to the modifier tab and click the down arrow.
- Select *Apply*

Comment: Now I can see the separate parts in edit mode, but I still have the total surrounding of the cylinder so the separate by loose parts does not work...

Comment: Select the cylinder and go to its object properties in the properties panel.  FInd "Viewport Display" and change "Display as" to either wire or bounds depending on what you want to see.  Or, you can always go to the Outliner and click the eye to make the cylinder disappear.

Comment: This operation only allows the modifier to be 'visible' in edit mode, though.

Answer (score 1):

Modifiers in BLender are **non destructive** which means it modifies the object without 'destroying' it i.e. your mesh will still remain at it's original state until you apply the modifier :
[image: Object mode]
[image: Edit mode before applying modifier]

If you want to work with the modified version of your cylinder, you need to **apply the modifier** (you may want to duplicate your object first since this operation is 'destructive') :

[image: Edit mode after applying the modifier]

In 2.8+ you can do that by clicking on the little arrow next to the camera icon near the modifier name and click on 'Apply' :

[image: in 2.8]

After that you can work on your 'booleaned' mesh in edit mode.

Note: You need to **exit edit mode before applying a modifier**.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. After the boolean difference I run following script:

```
    bpy.ops.object.convert(target='MESH')
```